# How to apply <extension()> attribute on class EntitySet(of TEntity)?

Tags: vb.net, linq

IDE is showing error in following code

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function FindByCode(Of TEntity)(ByRef vTEntities As EntitySet(Of TEntity), ByVal vCode As String) As TEntity
    Return (From oTEntity In vTEntities _
                            Where oTEntity.Code.Value = vCode _
                            Select oTentity).FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

The errors are:

1.Type argument 'TEntity' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'.

2.'Code' is not a member of 'TEntity'.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: it would help if you'd post the error message

Comment: also, your code is incomplete. What is oPersonName? You also have misspelled Extention (it should be Extension)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one problem is the `ByRef` part of the parameter declaration - extension methods require that the first parameter is `ByVal`. You're not *using* the fact that it's `ByRef` anyway...

Another problem is that this is generic - but you're *assuming* there's a property called `Code` which in turn has a property called `Value` - where are those assumptions coming from? You may want to constrain the `TEntity` type parameter, or possibly stop it from being generic in the first place.

EDIT: You'll *also* need to add a constraint to `TEntity` to force it to be a reference type:

FindByCode(Of TEntity As Class)

... but that won't help the fact that it doesn't know what the `Code` property is.

Comment: I replaced "ByRef" by "ByVal" the problem still persist